# Do I really need desktop sharing for one PC?

Tags: remote-desktop

I am running ubuntu 11.10.  I saw this thing about desktop sharing and saw what it was.  I also read that it takes up a lot of the PC's speed.  I am only on this computer and that is all I have.  Do I really need this desktop sharing feature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need desktop sharing.

Also,
If you're looking for a non-terminal solution to see processes like Windows task manager, use [ALT]+[F2], then type 'gnome-system-monitor' without the quotes. Pick the second tab. Under view, you may want to choose to see 'My processes', or 'All processes'. However, many processes are used by the system so tread carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Slightly longer answer: desktop sharing is only used if you want to view or control one computer from another computer.  Since you only have one computer, you couldn't even use desktop sharing.

Comment: David, thanks for the super quick and helpful reply. Are there other things I can uninstall to make this PC quicker? How do I see a list of the processes that are running?  You know in windows it was ctrl+alt+del and bam there it was.

Comment: @Brian To get a list of running processes, run `top` in a terminal window.  As far as things you can do to speed up your computer, yes there are **many** things you can do.  Use a lighter weight Desktop Environment (I use Xfce for example).  Switch to light weight alternatives of software you do use (abiword vs open office).